# Address Binding in ADA95?

Tags: ada, memory-address

We are in real time development which uses ADA languages( ADA95). We are facing problem with 
address binding mechanism. Prior we used ADA83 , in which are direct mechanism was
for x use at 16#12345678#;

Assign address 16#12345678# to variable x;but in ADA95 this syntax is not supported. Other way to assign is to declare a Record of variable . Then create object of some system
package then pass address.Which very cumbersome while to want to deal with a single variable. This method is suitable for only many variable with continuous memory location so that you assign address to first one , rest will be aligned automatically.

```
 TYPE SIU_Type IS                       
  RECORD
   SIU_Reserved0  : GLOBAL_TYPE.ORDINAL;
   MIDR           : GLOBAL_TYPE.ORDINAL;
   SIU_Reserved00 : GLOBAL_TYPE.ORDINAL;


  END RECORD;

  package SIU_Conv is new System.Address_To_Access_Conversions(SIU_Type);
  SIU : constant SIU_Conv.Object_Pointer := SIU_Conv.To_Pointer(SIU_Address);
```

In our project , we used variable at many places which need address assignment, but second way is very cubersome
and make code very complex.

Plaese Suggest any other way, if any.

Answer (score 5):

Ada95 syntax should be:
`for X'Address use System.Storage_Elements.To_Address(16#12345678#);`
To avoid any implicit initialization, you should also do: `pragma Import(Ada, X);`